# How can I collect custom contribution data in an event registration form?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, custom-fields, profile

People register for events. As part of that registration I want to collect some data that will be stored as part of their participant record. No problem.

I'd also like to collect information that will be stored as part of the contribution record linked to the event registration, but there seems to be no way to do this, as I can't access the profile containing the custom contribution fields in the online registration set-up for the event.

Am I missing something, or is the only way to do this by using a Drupal webform.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you cannot achieve this using a default event registration page. As you have mentioned, Drupal Webforms may be an option as well as using CiviRules or another extension/custom function that does some "magic".